# Using numpy.reshape in python

Tags: python

I am trying to use `numpy.reshape` to get a matrix of `2x100`. I have a list having 200 elements. Here is my code-
`vec` is my list containing 200 elements-

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Here is my code-

```
data=np.array(vec)
shape = ( 2, 100 )
data.reshape(shape)
print(data)
```

But I do not get a `2x100` matrix. This is what I get-

```
[1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reshape` does not modify the array.  It returns a new reshaped array.  Use `data = data.reshape(shape)`.